# How can i force android to paint the background of the statusbar?

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar, android-7.0-nougat, android-statusbar

With `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` the statusbar of my app is painted correctly, but when i set `android:targetSdkVersion="24"` the background of the statusbar of my app is not painted on android 8.0 (on lollipop the statusbar is painted correctly, no matter what i set in android:targetSdkVersion) . This is the style i use for my activity:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
  <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myDefaultEditText</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff2b2e38</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff0087b4</item>
</style>
```

My Activity is a descendant of `NativeActivity`. Starting from **api 24** the statusbar look like transparent and I m responsible to draw the background.

What was introduced in api 24 that can cause this behavior ? But most important, how can i force android to paint the background of the statusbar like lollipop do ?

Answer (score 1):

Android will use the `colorPrimaryDark` as the status bar colour.

colors.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#22222a</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#191a20</color>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Also, you should include the backwards compat version within your normal styles.xml

styles.xml

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

That will allow you to use that on older devices.

Comment: thanks @Advice-Dog, But unfortunately it's didn't work :( the background of the status bar is still not painted on android 8.0 :(